# dpiAware causes Invalid-Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I uncomment the following from a new mannifest:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
</windowsSettings>
```

and it causes this error when I publish it.

```
[24/02/2018 10:23:54 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/jorda/source/repos/Reminders/Reminders/publish/Application%20Files/Reminders_0_1_0_3/Reminders.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x8007001f
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
```

It actually does, as far as being able to test the manifest otherwise! It works perfectly not being aware! It works perfectly in debug and run.

How can I fix it?

EDIT: Okay. Am I stuck without DPI Awareness?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smondal/2013/12/02/a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning/

Comment: I just have 'application' which came with the created file.
But okay.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2017 and a Visual Basic application.
It installed well on computers just updated (win 10), but without latest update install failed.
Solved by going to project propertiies, selecting windows options. This is where you can comment out dpiaware, causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue lately... after some hours this post brought me some direction on what could be the problem. Commenting this part in the `app.manifest` file solved the problem. My solution is a Windows application using WPF.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```